# Action with more than one instance of a rule or token

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I have the following grammar rule:

```
pacman
  : section section map section
  ;
```

I want to write a Java action for this rule that processes the three different `section`s differently. What are the handles for the three different instances?

---

This is psuedocode showing what I want:

```
pacman
  : section section map section
  {
    processFirstSection($section[0]);
    if(checkSecondSection($section[1]))
    {
      //The if statement isn't important itself;
      //the point is that I do completely different
      //things with each section
      handleThirdSection($section[2]);
    }
  }
  ;
```

Comment: It depends what you mean by "processes them differently". If you mean different parser rules must be applied, ANTLR figures that out for you by trying them. If it's something you *can't* handle via parser rules, consider using a Listener and validating/acting upon the parse tree afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pacman
  : section1=section section2=section map section3=section
  {
    processFirstSection($section1);
    if(checkSecondSection($section2))
    {
      handleThirdSection($section3);
    }
  }
```

In general, the rule

```
 rule : name=Token otherName=rule
```

lets you access the token `Token` using `$name` and the rule `rule` using `$otherName`.

Comment: This works in Antlr3.  If you are using Antlr4, you would use a similar syntax for the rules (section1=section section2=section ...) but you would not have an action.  The Context passed the Listener would then have fields named section1, section2 and section3.